# Problem connecting telegram bot through Python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I was trying to set up a telegram bot using Python according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwBWW8cNCP4). The final script I wrote in Python is

```
import telebot

bot_name='gfjhsbot'
bot_api='1529995319:AAGb34vl-FkYRESLMZuIsTdrlLlP7mPHEyw'

bot=telebot.TeleBot(bot_api)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['greet'])
def greet_func(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,'The first telegram bot is cool!')

bot.polling()
```

Normally, it should work, but unfortunately, telegram is filtered and I connect to my own account through proxies, like the following image from my telegram windows environment:
[image]

One of my proxy samples is

```
https://t.me/proxy?server=3.66.228.40&port=443&secret=dd7aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcd61
```

To this reason, the above Python script does not work (when running the script and writing `/greet` as command in the bot, I do not get the response `'The first telegram bot is cool!'` I expect), returning the following error after about 5 seconds:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1529995319:AAGb34vl-FkYRESLMZuIsTdrlLlP7mPHEyw/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')")))
```

Question

> How can I connect to telegram bot through proxy using a Python line of code?

Thanks in advance!