# pyTelegramBotAPI connection problem or what?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

this is my code:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["greet"])
def greeting(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi")

bot.polling()
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 496, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 573, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1494641875:AAEPX72rP7YFT0ZZzASh0cn9rAw6l8PUMk0/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Programming/Python/Training/TelegramBot02/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 455, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 478, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 88, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 295, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout = long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 265, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 248, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 107, in _make_request
    result = _get_req_session().request(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1494641875:AAEPX72rP7YFT0ZZzASh0cn9rAw6l8PUMk0/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Connection is OK. Token is OK. It works manually when I browse https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getme and it works fine.
Other site for example google.com are OK too and works fine.
I would be glad to know what is the problem.

Actually because error I receive is too much a lot, stackoverflow does not allow me to post the question and wants me to add some more details, so I wrote this paragraph which is not related to the question and is just some words.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have connected your telegram with a proxy? I can't solve your problem but you can follow this post: [Problem connecting telegram bot through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054113/problem-connecting-telegram-bot-through-python)